# Как работать с версткой в данном случае в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Скачал шаблон `html`, чтобы по нему создать интернет-магазин. Создал `layout`, вынес в него шапку и футер, по середине контент, всё как надо. Но загвоздка для меня заключается в следующем: есть меню категорий, жму, допустим, на напитки. Я думал, что все категории между собой будут схожи, но в верстке специально показано, как должна выглядеть каждая категория, и они все немного разные.

Вопрос: Мне надо создать ЕЩЕ один `layout`, куда вынесу общее между категориями? Или например рендерить для каждой категории свой вид (но сразу думаю, что это очень плохо), выглядит сейчас это так:

В контроллере категорий я получаю `id` категории, и делаю следующее:

```
$id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
$products = \app\models\Product::find()->where(['category_id' => $id])->all();
switch($id) {
    case 5:
        return $this->render('viewApple', compact('products'));
        break;

}
```

То есть я думаю перехватить `id` каждой категории и под нее рендерить свой вид. То есть тут `id = 5` — это категория яблок (в целом фруктов), `id = 6` — будет категория овощей, и придется добавить

```
case 6:
    return $this->render('viewVegetables', compact('products'));
    break;
```

Прошу помощи. Опыта с этим всем очень мало. Ранее работал с магазином, в котором везде шапка и футер одинаковые, тут немного разнится это.

Comment: А можете показать что там как должно выглядеть? фото категорий)

Answer (score 1):

В коде в любом случае придется или переключать layout или выбирать свое представление.Четкого ответа не будет, можно делать по разному, в качестве примера, приведу один из вариантов.

К категории (в базе), еще указываете шаблон - main, apple, vegetables, и т.д. В итоге на этапе добавления вы будите знать шаблон категории

В контроллере:

```
$products = ...;
$category = Category::findById($category_id);

$view = !empty($category->template)?'view-'.$category->template:'view-main';
$this->render($view, ['products'=>$products, 'category'=>$category]);
```

Код, просто как пример. Собственно, выбираем категории, если указан шаблон, то будет искать представление, с названием указанным в базе, если нет, то некий общий шаблон для всех.

Answer (score 0):

Можно для разных страниц делать разные layout и применять... **От layout лучше не отказываться**

```
$this->layout = '@app/views/layouts/apple';
```

Для самих категорий лучше добавить поле template, и в моделе добавить метод для его определения...к примеру следующим образом

```
class Category...
{
    public function getTemplate(){ 
       return !empty($this->template) ? $this->template : 'main';
    }
}
```

Если у вас есть связи, метод можно потом вызывать вот так

```
$product->category->getTemplate();
```

или просто

```
$category->getTemplate();
```